# How do I properly link libssh?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cmake

I'm trying to include a lib into my code (libssh) but nothing works... 
At this point I'm unsure what to do as no results are popping up in search engines for the errors i'm recieving.

I downloaded libssh here:
https://github.com/substack/libssh

I installed these:

```
yum install cmake zlib-devel libpng-devel openssl-devel -y;
```

Created a "build" directory as parent of libssh, moved there, typed this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
make


[root@ build]# cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug LD_DEBUG=all ..
-- Could NOT find NaCl (missing:  NACL_LIBRARIES NACL_INCLUDE_DIRS)
-- ********************************************
-- ********** libssh build options : **********
-- zlib support: ON
-- libgcrypt support: OFF
-- libnacl support: OFF
-- SSH-1 support: OFF
-- SFTP support: ON
-- Server support : ON
-- GSSAPI support : ON
-- Pcap debugging support : ON
-- With static library: OFF
-- Unit testing: OFF
-- Client code Unit testing: OFF
-- Public API documentation generation
-- Benchmarks: OFF
-- ********************************************
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/libssh/build
```

And then it fails...

```
Scanning dependencies of target exec
[  2%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/exec.dir/exec.c.o
[  5%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/exec.dir/authentication.c.o
[  8%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/exec.dir/knownhosts.c.o
[ 11%] Building C object examples/CMakeFiles/exec.dir/connect_ssh.c.o
Linking C executable exec
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssh_shared
collect2: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
make[2]: *** [examples/exec] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/exec.dir/all] Erreur 2
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
```

Anyone know what the problem is? "cannot find -lssh_shared" showed me nothing related on google.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is resulted from the linker `/usr/bin/ld` is failed to link to the library `ssh_shared.so` while compiling.

I checked the file `libssh/build/src/CMakeFiles/ssh_shared.dir/build.make`, there's some linking messages inside:

```
ssh_shared_EXTERNAL_OBJECTS =
src/libssh.so.4.2.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
src/libssh.so.4.2.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
src/libssh.so.4.2.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so

... (snippet here) ...
src/libssh.so.4.2.0: src/CMakeFiles/ssh_shared.dir/bind.c.o
src/libssh.so.4.2.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
src/libssh.so.4.2.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
src/libssh.so.4.2.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
src/libssh.so.4.2.0: src/CMakeFiles/ssh_shared.dir/build.make
src/libssh.so.4.2.0: src/CMakeFiles/ssh_shared.dir/link.txt

@$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --red --bold "Linking C shared library libssh.so"
```

You can notice that during the build process, `cmake` would try to link some libraries under my system path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. And go to check yours.

Comment: I'm a little unsure how you do that? I thought it needed to be done through cmake? I don't see any ssh_shared.so on the system at all.

Comment: Did you encounter the failure while you execute `make`? Can you show me the related command to build "connect_ssh.c.o" in the makefile?

Comment: Yes it was using make, now it's throwing all these errors, not sure what I changed... Losing hope, linking libs is apparently very advanced stuff lol is there another way of doing this without cmake? I followed the guide step by step.

CMakeFiles/exec.dir/exec.c.o: In function `main':
/root/libssh/examples/exec.c:16: undefined reference to `ssh_finalize'

Comment: You definitely need to link every required library before you compiled successfully. The linker `ld` would try to link specific libraries under its search path. For your problem now, `ssh_finalize` is also defined in `libssh.so`, so you need to fix the linking problem as well. :(

Comment: I try to build libssh, and there's no problem here. I made some modifications in my answer, hoped that can help you.

Comment: @CWLiu The error is a result of the linker failing to link against `libssh_shared.so` (the `lib` is implied the `-lssh...`) If you go looking for a file, `ssh_shared.so`, you will never determine whether the lib is there or not. You should be looking for `libssh_shared.so` in your library directory. If you are using a package for your distro, then the lib search path should be correct and `/sbin/ldconfig` should automatically be called by a post install script, if required.

Comment: Not sure what it was, after there was more errors that weren't even there before, and yes @David C. Rankin I tried looking for ssh_shared.so without success. I did the exact same steps on 2 other servers and it installed fine.. Weird.